# What system has a spectral series in the radio spectrum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, potential-energy, cold-atoms, rydberg-states

As an electron energy level has an emission level depending upon the excitation, is it possible for a system such as a Rydberg atom to have emissions in the low side of the frequency range?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is perfectly possible. Rydberg atoms are one example, transitions within the hyperfine structure are another. However, for something as small as an atom the strength of the signal (characterized by the relevant matrix element or line strength) is very low. This means that such transitions do not happen spontaneously on reasonable timescales, but they can be observed by absorption or stimulated emission or Rabi flopping.

Comment: Andrew, does a Rydberg atom have its spectra in the far IR, microwave or radio wave range? Also, is there the generation of many Rydberg atoms, which then all have a simultaneous relaxation, and this was previously excited with radio waves?

Comment: @HolgerFiedler I only have some general knowledge here. A Rydberg atom has energy levels going roughly as $1/n^2$ so for high enough $n$ you get IR, microwave and radio wave. However such atoms are very fragile and the emissions very weak as I already said. It is in principle possible to have a large number of such atoms emitting together, but I don't know how practical that is, or whether it occurs in some unusual astronomical setting.